# Adobe Analytics 2.0 API: Is it possible to get report data across multiple dimensions (date,country,region,city,zip) without excessive api calls

Tags: adobe-analytics

I'm trying to get data for multiple metrics(visits, orders, revenue, units, pageviews). Now I want this across the dimensions (daterangeday, geocountry, georegion, geocity zip).  I'm using adobe's 2.0 api. I need something like the below table.

| date | country | region | city | zip | orders | revenue | pageViews |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| May 29, 2021 | United States | New York | Brooklyn | 11201 | 10 | 30 | 30 |
| May 30, 2021 | United States | New York | Brooklyn | 11201 | 10 | 50 | 30 |
| May 29, 2021 | United States | New York | Bronx | 10458 | 10 | 20 | 30 |

Now I did read about multiple breakdowns https://www.adobe.io/apis/experiencecloud/analytics/docs.html#!AdobeDocs/analytics-2.0-apis/master/reporting-multiple-breakdowns.md

However to get the data I need, I would have to:

1. Get metrics by date.
2. Loop through each date and Get itemId
3. Get metrics by country and apply individual date using itemId in metric filters.
4. Repeat the same for other dimensions (loop and add more metricFilters)
5. Stop at lowest level (zip).

That would result in way too many api calls (30 days * no of countries * no of regions per country * zip etc)

Is there no way to give multiple dimensions in an array (As was possible in 1.4 api)?
Is there something else I can add in the request json?

Please let me know if any more information is needed. Thanks!

Comment: Presumably you are using the default/global/top level `dimension` property for your first dimension. If you want to add additional dimensions, you can add them in `rowContainer.rowFilters` in the payload. `rowFilters` is an array of objects to specify additional rows, e.g. `rowContainer.rowFilters[0].dimension`. Unfortunately, the API 2.0 doc (still) isn't fully fleshed out, but you can see a more definitive possible payload on their interactive [Swagger UI](https://adobedocs.github.io/analytics-2.0-apis/) page.

Comment: Hey @CrayonViolent ! Thanks for responding. I've been trying out the rowContainer in payload, but I was not able to figure it out. Should doing something like `"rowContainer": {"rows": [{"rowId": "variables/country"}]}` while giving `daterangeday` as my top level dimension give me a response with both date and zip and those metrics? I tried it and got the same response.

Would you be able to share an example payload which uses rowContainer. I could understand the schema of rowContainer payload from swagger but could not really use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible to retrieve multiple dimensions in a single report request in the 2.0 API. This has been discussed in the [2.0 API Docs github repo](https://github.com/AdobeDocs/analytics-2.0-apis/issues/225) in the past, but as of today that feature isn't available and you have to make multiple requests to get data for multiple dimensions.